# What does an Up Arrow Next to Project Name Mean in MercurialEclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I'm using mercurial and MercurialEclipse.  I just merged one of my projects and now I have, to the right of the project name in package explorer, "default {up arrow symbol} 2"

At first I thought this meant I had two tips, but looking at it with tortoise or "hg log" it seems to only have the one tip.

What does the up arrow mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you have 2 local changesets that have not yet been pushed to the central repo.  If you synchronize the project (right click on project-->Team-->Synchrozize), or do **hg out** on the command line, you should see them.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I had 2 changesets, but didn't make the connection to the MercurialEclipse visual cues